# How to get items from a list based on specific item in Python

Tags: python, list

I have below list

```
l = ['7E', '00', '10', '97', '9A', '00', '13', 'A2', '00', '41', 'B6', '13', '58', 'FF', 'FE', '41', '50', '00', '01', '28']
```

From above list, I want to extract `41 B6 13 58`, which always comes after `00 13 A2 00` and is always length 4.

I thought of extracting this based on the index of `00` (just before `41`) but there can be many `00` in the list so this will not be always correct.

So I have to make sure it's always `00 13 A2 00` and then get the index of `00` (which is after `A2`) and from this index extract next 4 items which should be the final output. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by extract? Do you want to check if that sequence exists in a given list or do you want to find the index where such a sequence starts, if it exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(l)-8):
    if l[i:i+4] == ['00', '13', 'A2', '00']:
        return l[i+4:i+8]
```

So what we are doing: looking linearly for those four given values (indices `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`, and `i+3`), and if we find them, we take the next four values from the list - indices `i+4`, `i+5`, `i+6`, and `i+7`.

Comment: `[l[i], l[i+1], l[i+2], l[i+3]]` can be shortened to `l[i:i+4]` same with `l[i+4:i+8]`

Comment: Awesome addition, thanks. Edited to include :)

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['7E', '00', '10', '97', '9A', '00', '13', 'A2', '00', '41', 'B6', '13', '58', 'FF', 'FE', '41', '50', '00', '01', '28']
SEQUENCE = "00 13 A2 00"


str_l = " ".join(l)
print(str_l)

position = str_l.find(SEQUENCE)   # this gives us the position where the sequence starts
print(position)

required = "xx xx xx xx"    # assuming we dont know what exactly to extract, but we know its length
req = str_l[position+len(SEQUENCE)+1: position + len(SEQUENCE)+len(required)+1]
print(req)  

# to get the required output
req = req.split(" ")
print(req)
```